# SQL Server Compact timed out waiting for a lock - Orchard CMS

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/472561

I'm using Orchard CMS where I'm currently retrofitting my project onto version 1.7.2 from 1.6. I first got this error upon creating a specific Content Item:

```
could not insert: [Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemRecord][SQL: INSERT INTO Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord (Data, ContentType_id) VALUES (?, ?)]

SQL Server Compact timed out waiting for a lock. The default lock time is 2000ms for devices and 5000ms for desktops. The default lock timeout can be increased in the connection string using the ssce: default lock timeout property. [ Session id = 2,Thread id = 16096,Process id = 10760,Table name = Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord,Conflict type = x lock (x blocks),Resource = PAG (idx): 1066 ]
```

Afterwhich, I couldn't create any Content Item at all and just kept on getting this:

```
null id in Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

I'm still in the process of validating if this was caused by a specific Content Type that had custom parts and tables (1-n relationships), but as of now I'm seeing the problem even with plain Content Types that use the existing fields within Orchard (just text fields, really).

But in case anyone else has seen this and has some ideas, kindly share anything you have, it would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have isolated the issue with SQL CE. I used SQL Server and haven't encountered this major error since. But I still want this resolved, so just post any ideas people! Thanks

Comment: Hi AnimaSola, I experienced this issue recently also. Restarting my machine seemed to resolve the issue.